# стоит ли убирать геттер, если нужен только сеттер?

Tags: ооп

Если мне нужно только переустанавливать значения поля, а доступ на чтение к нему не нужен, стоит ли мне предоставить для этого поля только сеттер? Или все таки лучше создать еще и геттер "на будущее"?

Comment: Ответ на данный вопрос зависит от предпочтений конкретного разработчика. Поэтому точный ответ вы не получите.

Comment: @u_mulder Например, точным будет тот ответ, который опишет подводные камни связанные с этим, недостатки и преимущества. Считайте что это вопрос с Programmers.SE

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455849/interface-setter-without-a-getter

Comment: Мне кажется недостаток создания геттера на будущее - в том что мы плодим ненужные методы. Ведь никто не помешает нам его создать в тот момент когда понадобится доступ на чтение к этому полю. Преимуществ не вижу совсем никаких. Подводных камней в том что бы не создавать геттер "на будущее" тоже. Поправьте пожалуйста, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров скажу одну слово - "инкапсуляция".

Comment: @Suvitruf, не понимаю( а чем непредоставление геттера нарушает инкапсуляцию? Я же не собираюсь делать поле публичным или открывать какую-либо другую реализацию

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, геттер публичный или нет?

Если публичный, то стоит определиться, должно ли быть свойство доступно на чтение. Если нет, то и суда нет, не надо делать геттер.

Если `private`/`protected`, то это вопрос удобства.

Скажем, есть у нас:

```
public class MyClass{
   private MyField myField;

   public void setMyField(MyField value){
      myField = value;
   }
}
```

Если у нас есть класс наследник, который должен иметь доступ к полю, то мы либо делаем свойство `protected`, либо делаем `protected` геттер на него.

В чём плюсы геттера? Если в базовом классе решите поменять название поля, к примеру, то вам после этого надо будет поменять только геттер. Если же нет геттера, то везде, где у вас обращение к `this.myField` придётся вносить изменения.

В общем, единственная причина **не делать** геттер - это когда вам необходимо, чтобы к полю нельзя было обратиться. Но мне видится это странным: сеттер без геттера. Если вам необходимо лишь устанавливать значение, но запретить доступ на чтение, то лучше это делать с помощью билдера или передавать в конструкторе.

Да и если рассуждать логически, то тот, кто вызвал сеттер, уже и так знает значение, поэтому в надобности геттера нет вовсе.

Comment: да, мне было интересно именно про публичный геттер. А речь идет о поле, которое является ArrayList-ом. Я не хочу делать для него геттер, потому что через этот геттер можно же добавить к нему элемент, например. А в конструкторе передавать и убирать сеттер тоже не вариант - получается что каждый раз, когда нужно изменить всего одно поле, придется создавать новый объект. А билдер - это вы паттерн имеете в виду?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров да, паттерн Билдер, когда объект конструируется лишь один раз вначале.

Comment: @Suvirtuf, спасибо за направление, буду разбираться